# How to remove the name Chapter with fanchyhdr in Report class

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr

I try

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

but is not effect.

I need 1.First Chapter on head.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command works fine. It is explained in the documentation:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{chaptername here}
text here
\clearpage
text here
\clearpage
text here
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The problem of Regis was a little bit difficult because the definiton was inside a sty-file in a separate command. We solved the problem in a chat-room.

Comment: Thanks, but and 1.chaptername here?

Comment: In the example the name "chapter" is removed and only the number of the chapter and the given "chapter-name" is printed in the header.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1067/discussion-between-marco-and-regis-da-silva)